# Google Play Design Guidelines?

Tags: google-play

Does any document from google exist that gives guidelines for the graphical design of a google play site?

Such guidelines exist, for example, for android icons http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1078870

Resource titled: Graphic Assets for your Application